# Hiding/Removing Master Page Navigation Items From another page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have this Master Page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title><%: Page.Title %></title>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Styles/css" />
<link href="~/Images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <asp:LoginView id="lvLoginRegister" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul id="rightNavBar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li id="liRegister"><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                            <li id="liLogin"><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <hr />
        <footer>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I was able to access my `<LoginView>` Control and am able to hide that but how do I hide the ul and li items?

If I hide LoginView Control, it hides the whole thing but I only want to hide the items.

```
LoginView navLoginRegister = (LoginView)this.Master.FindControl("lvLoginRegister");    
navLoginRegister.Visible = false -- Works
HtmlGenericControl liLogin = (HtmlGenericControl)navLoginRegister.FindControl("liLogin");
liLogin.Visible = false; --Doesn't work
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the answer below was what you were looking for, or it helped you find the answer, please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `li` control doesn't get discovered on server side, because it is not a server control. Just add `runat="server"` to the `liLogin` control, like this

```
<li id="liLogin" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a>
</li>
```

You might also wish to add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the new server `li` control, if you need to use its id `liLogin` on client side in the future. This way you would be able to deal with id name `liLogin` instead of an unexpected id name. More on `ClientIdMode` can you find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx).